# Need to replace all the cells with "0" values in an excel array with blank using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I need to run a macro that replace all the cells in an array that contain "0" only as value with a blank
At the same time, cells that contains 0 and other text/numbers eg. "Test01" should not be considered and left as they are

this is the code i wrote but it is really slow on a 3k row sheet

```
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Nuova Base Dati")
sht.Activate
Set rng = Range(Range("B2"), Range("E" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.count))
For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Value = ""
Next
```

Any suggestion to make it quicker?

Comment: Use [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) on the entire range, without looping?

Comment: If `Replace()` can't do it, set an array, `dim arr as variant`, and set that range to the array, `arr = Range(Range("B2"), Range("E" & sht.UsedRange.Rows.count))`, then work on that array.

Comment: Add two lines above the loop `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and below the loop `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: thanks all i solved it wit @Toddleson input :)

Comment: @Matteo - that suggestion is like putting a band-aid on an arterial wound. The answer is not to loop cell-by-cell.

Comment: @BigBen It's not optimal, but its easy :P

Comment: @BigBen thanks i used the quick and dirty solution but take in consideration your feedback as well for further improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the next code. It uses two arrays and should be fast enough for a large range, too:

```
Sub ReplaceZero()
  Dim shT As Worksheet, arrE, r As Long, c As Long, arrFin
  Set shT = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Nuova Base Dati")

 'place the range to be processed in an array (for faster iteration):
 arrE = shT.Range(shT.Range("B2"), shT.Range("E" & shT.UsedRange.Rows.count)).Value2
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrE), 1 To UBound(arrE, 2)) 'set dimensions of the final array, keeping the processing result
 For r = 1 To UBound(arrE)         'iterate between the array rows
    For c = 1 To UBound(arrE, 2)  'iterate between the array columns
        If arrE(r, c) = 0 Then
            arrFin(r, c) = ""             'write a null string in case of zero
        Else
             arrFin(r, c) = arrE(r, c)  'keep the existing value, if not zero
        End If
    Next c
 Next r
 'Drop the processed array content, at once:
 shT.Range("B2").resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

The above code is fast, but **in case of formula involved** it will transform the formulas in their values...

Comment: @BigBen Yes! Are there formulas involved? I did not see any mention about that...

Comment: @BigBen Yes, you are right! I will edit my answer and mention that. Thanks!